# Implement Navigation Drawer on Activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've created a Navigation Drawer in Android Studio with : File > New > Activity > Navigation Drawer Activity. 
It work very good, but how I can add this Navigation Drawer in my mainactivity or in other activity? Because it's a problem, It's two different activity...
Sorry for my English i'm French :(

Comment: You could read the documentation on adding the drawer manually. The template has a lot of unnecessary code and you'll understand it better if you do it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Navigation Drawer activity` template has only one activity, If you want to use this template then that activity should be your main activity.

I mean simply move your old `main activity`'s code to the Navigation Drawer's activity which created with the template and make it your new App's main activity!

Otherwise, you will have to implement The navigation drawer in your old `main activity` just like the template does

==

**Update**:

The `Navigation Drawer activity` template has 4 different `xml` layouts which usually named:

1- `activity_main.xml` contains the `DrawerLayout` and includes no. 2

2- `app_bar_main.xml` contains the action bar xml code and includes no. 3

3- `content_main.xml` **this should be your main layout**

4- `nav_header_main` contains the top view of the drawer

Note: names might be different depending on the Drawer's activity name.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but how i can add the xml of the mainactivity in the xml of navigation drawer (lot of different xml).

Comment: Thank you very much you're awesome, you saved me I was about to give up :D